# decrypt TLS 1.2 AES-GCM packet

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

I'm working on a Java program to decrypt a **TLS 1.2** Session which is using the `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` cipher. I recorded a test session using wireshark. The **Master Secret** is known.

```
No.     Time           Protocol Length Info
      4 0.000124000    TLSv1.2  166    Client Hello
      6 0.000202000    TLSv1.2  1074   Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
      8 0.001071000    TLSv1.2  393    Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Finished
      9 0.003714000    TLSv1.2  301    New Session Ticket, Change Cipher Spec, Finished
     11 6.443056000    TLSv1.2  116    Application Data
     12 6.443245000    TLSv1.2  765    Application Data
     15 6.443390000    TLSv1.2  103    Alert (Level: Warning, Description: Close Notify)
```

`Packet 11` Contains a `HTTP GET Request`  that I'm trying to decrypt.

**Handshake Data:**

```
Cipher:        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Client Random: 375f5632ba9075b88dd83eeeed4adb427d4011298efb79fb2bf78f4a4b7d9d95
Server Random: 5a1b3957e3bd1644e7083e25c64f137ed2803b680e43395a82e5b302b64ba763    
Master Secret: 2FB179AB70CD4CA2C1285B4B1E294F8F44B7E8DA26B62D00EE35181575EAB04C
           4FA11C0DA3ABABB4AF8D09ACB4CCC3CD
```

**Packet 11 Data:**

```
Direction is Client -> Server.
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol: Application Data
    Content Type: Application Data (23)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 45
    Encrypted Application Data: c91de005e2ae50a8a57abee55c183667b136343feef4a387cb7cf83030a47e230af268378c4f33c8b5bab3d26d
```

***What I have done so far:***

**Key Derivation:**

I only need Client keys here, as I want to decrypt a Client->Server package. I expanded server and client keys and IVs as per RFC.

`Client Write Key: 4B119DFBFC930ABE130030BD53C3BF78
Client Write IV:  2029CAE2`

**Nonce:**

I create AES-GCM nonce from salt (=Client Write IV) and explicit nonce (=first 8 Byte of encrypted data).

`Salt:          2029CAE2
explicitNonce: C91DE005E2AE50A8
Nonce:         2029CAE2C91DE005E2AE50A8`

**Additional Authentication Data (AAD):**

This is where I apparently got stuck. The RFC5246 says:

> additional_data = seq_num + TLSCompressed.type +
>                     TLSCompressed.version + TLSCompressed.length;
>   where "+" denotes concatenation.

So I made this:

```
byte[] aad = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,   // seq_no uint64
    0x17,               // type 0x17 = Application Data
    0x03, 0x03,             //  TLS Version 1.2
    0, 45};             // 45 Bytes of encrypted data
```

I think `seq_no` is 1. It gets reset to zero, when `Change Cipher Spec` record is sent. (`Packet #8`) Then the encrypted `Finished` record has `seq_no = 0`. And the next client packet is our `Packet #11`  with `seq_no = 1`.

**Code:**

Now I'm feeding everything into BouncyCastle:

```
AEADParameters parameters = new AEADParameters(new KeyParameter(clientWriteKey), 128, nonce, aad);
GCMBlockCipher gcmBlockCipher = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
gcmBlockCipher.init(false, parameters);
byte[] plainText = new byte[gcmBlockCipher.getOutputSize(cipherText.length)];
try {
    int decLen = gcmBlockCipher.processBytes(cipherText, 0, cipherText.length, plainText, 0);
    decLen += gcmBlockCipher.doFinal(plainText, decLen);
} catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
    System.out.println("MAC failed: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

This always throws **MAC failed: mac check in GCM failed**. **BUT** the decrypted output is correct:

```
byte[] decomp = decompress(plainText);
System.out.println(new String(decomp, "UTF-8"));
```

***This prints `GET / HTTP/1.0\n`.***

Decompress helper:

```
public static byte[] decompress(byte[] data) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater(true);
    inflater.setInput(data);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (inflater.getRemaining() > 0) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();

    inflater.end();
    return output;
    }
```

**Conclusion:**
As the decrypted output is correct, i can safely assume that key derivation and decryption are working fine. Only authentication fails. So I think maybe I'm doing something wrong with the Additional Authentication Data (AAD).
So this question boils down to:

**How are the Additional Authentication Data (AAD) correctly assembled?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCM mode computes MAC from message, associated data and public nonce, you covered it very well.

I think you are using wrong length, it should be plaintext length before encrypting and appending MAC. Try 45 - 8 (explicit nonce) - 16 (MAC) = 21.